# Understanding broadcasting in context with tensors

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Consider  vectors of two elements stored in an matrix. Suppose the matrix X is of shape (300,2).
I want to calculate the euclidean norm between each vector.
Using broadcasting it should look like as follows:

```
# (300, 1, 2)  -  (1, 300, 2) -> (300, 300, 2)
np.sum( (X[:, None]  - X[None])**2, axis=2)**0.5
```

The result is of size (300,300). I do not quite understand how summing along axis=2 works. I have 300 of (300,2) matrices. Can anybody give me some intution how my desired result follows from that?

Comment: Is the euclidean norm the same as L2 norm? You are doing an outer subtraction on X and as you say it will result in the shape ```(300, 300, 2)```. The summation is to add the two pairs for each component of the outer subtraction (look at Pythagoras). You are summing along the second axis (the one with dimension size 2).

Comment: What don't you understand, the broadcasting in `X[:, None]  - X[None])**2` or the sum on the size 2 dimension of that result.  Explaining the code is one thing, satisfying your individual intuition is harder.

Comment: I do not unterstand how the difference is evaluated. I subtract each of my 300 vectors simultaneously , such that i.e. the first   (300,2) matrix contains the difference from vector 1 to alle others and so on?